# How to send an invoice with details to the customers

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to send an invoice with detailes to the customers when they payed via credit card using Stripe.
I want when someone buy something, he or she will get an confirmation email with the details.

Note: if it's possible can the customers pay via invoice with Credit Card instead of direct with Credit Card using Stripe, because I want to avoid Stripe fees.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what this stripe stuff is but you can see the emails WooCommerce will be sending if you go to this url - /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=email

Or was it something more specific than this? :S

Comment: Thank you but I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer for invoice is that Woocommerce by default can send an invoice usin WP_mail() but if you not getting the invoice so it might be a plugin or your theme is blocking the email which have the invoice. Try to use Mail logs plugin to see the error.

The Answer for Stripe etc... is that every company like Strips or Paypal needs to earn money to let you use their tools for almost free. So it's not possible to find such free tools to make it do the job, because it cost money to let every thing work with good performance like Strips and Paypal do.